# Is partitioning still needed if the tables are already sharded in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

Background: MySQL 5.7, InnoDB Engine

We have a huge transaction log table (6 million new rows per day) and we want to shard this huge table into multiple mysql instances and tables (so we have table_001, table_002, etc). Users often query their recent rows which means recent rows are hot while old rows are cold.

I'm wondering if mysql partitions are still needed in each sharded table (table_001, table_002, etc) in this case. My opinion is NO. If we already sharded the data into many sub-tables, why we need another kind of sub-tables by using partitions? (Partitions are actually separate tables internally right?)

Comment: Table partitioning means creation of separate tables for each partition - correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways to split up a table:

- "Sharding" -- some rows on each of several *servers*.  This is useful for 'write scaling'.  (Seems not applicable to you.)
- "Partitioning" -- a special syntax that builds sub-tables, but reference it *as if it were a single table*.  There are very few cases where performance is enhanced by such.  We need to see your queries to discuss this further.
- Manually splitting a table into `table_001`, etc -- Again and again, this is suggested on this forum.  It is always shot down as a bad idea.
- "Replication" -- By having lots of Slaves hanging off the one Master, you can gain "read scaling".  This would allow more queries at the same time.  (I don't see this as being the 'right' solution for you.)  In Replication, you must write to one place, and you get many identical copies of the data.

Will you be removing "old" data?  If so, `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` makes purging much more efficient.  But it does not necessarily improve `SELECT` performance; let's see your `SELECTs`.

Will you be "summarizing" the data, a la Data Warehousing "reports"?  If so, we can discuss this further.

**re: INSERTion rate**

With InnoDB, a single big table is essentially as easy to `INSERT` into as multiple small tables or multiple partitions.  200 is not a very big insertion rate.

- Do you "batch" the inserts?  That is, `INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ...;`?  Or use `LOAD DATA`?  Either of those is likely to sustain over 1000/sec.
- Do you have lots of `INDEXes`?  They are somewhat a burden on high insertion rate.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss further.
- Do you have multiple threads doing `INSERTs`?
- For really high insertion rates, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) .
- SSDs allow even higher insertion rates.

Comment: That data is heavily written. We already planned to go for "sharding", so we'll have multiple mysql instances, in which there are multiple databases, and in each database there are multiple tables like 'table_001', 'table_002', etc. What I would like to confirm is, if partitioning is still needed in the sub-tables (table_001, table_002, etc).

Comment: @MouhongLin - No partitioning, no multiple table per instance.  Instead just Shard.  Please provide (1) ingestion rate (rows per second), (2) sample `SELECTs` (3) whether you will purge old data.  With those I can either agree with your approach, or explain why your approach won't help.

Comment: About 200 writes per second. Selects is rare so I think read only slaves will not help. By smaller tables, I would like to keep the table small so DDL operations will be easier.

Comment: @MouhongLin - "premature optimization".  We can probably do 200/sec on a single server into a single table.  See what I added to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks Rich. But one single table will result in large tables which will make DDL operations hard in future?

Comment: @MouhongLin - DDL (normally) is not needed after the table is initially created.  What DDLs do you anticipate?  (Some are still hard with split up tables.)

Comment: I think it might happen although it's rare. Sorry, the peek insert rate is about 1k/s.

Comment: @MouhongLin - With 1K `INSERTs`/sec, you need SSDs and/or batching of the inserts.